# How can I surround numbers with Math Ml tags?

Tags: java, xml, regex

I am trying to surround numbers with XML tags. I'd like my output to be `<mo>11</mo>`. Instead, I get the strangest output.
Below is my code, followed by the strange output.

```
package javaapplication8;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Program {

    static String phrase = "Hi, I am number 123 just so you know. And, he is 11, also,     just so you know.";
    static StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(phrase);
    static final Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    static final Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(phrase);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (myMatcher.find()) {
            builder.replace(myMatcher.start(), myMatcher.end(), "<mo>" + myMatcher.group() + "</mo>");
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hi, I am number <mo>123</mo> just so you know. An<mo>11</mo> he is 11, also, just so you know.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Now you have two problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do something a little simpler, for example

```
// Add a <mo> </mo> tag around numerical runs in input.
public static String tagDigits(String in) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  boolean inDigitRun = false;
  for (char ch : in.toCharArray()) {
    if (!inDigitRun) {
      if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
        sb.append("<mo>");
        inDigitRun = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
        inDigitRun = false;
        sb.append("</mo>");
      }
    }
    sb.append(ch);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String phrase = "Hi, I am number 123 just so you know. "
      + "And, he is 11, also,     just so you know.";
  System.out.println(tagDigits(phrase));
}
```

Which will output

```
Hi, I am number <mo>123</mo> just so you know. And, he is <mo>11</mo>, also,     just so you know.
```

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.. - Jamie Zawinski - 1997

Of course, your could also do

```
public static String tagDigits(String in) {
  if (in == null) {
    return "";
  }
  return in.replaceAll("\\d+", "<mo>$0</mo>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indexes of matched part from original String are not the same as the ones from string after first `replace` operations (you added `"<mo>"` and `"</mo>"` to this String so characters after them ware moved to farther positions). Try maybe different approach with `replaceAll` method

```
System.out.println(phrase.replaceAll("\\d+", "<mo>$0</mo>"));
```

Output:

```
Hi, I am number <mo>123</mo> just so you know. And, he is <mo>11</mo>, also,     just so you know.
```

Here we are using regex `\\d+` to match numbers and place it in group 0. Later in replacement part we can refer to match from group 0 via `$0` operator.